# How can i restore functionality to my recovery partition? Disk management shows its empty, yet its not

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

So i've somehow lost my recovery partition, or at least its not being tethered to my current windows install.

I tried to create a recovery drive and was greeted with "some files are missing" or some such.

I proceeded to check diskmgt and it is there.  Disk 0, partition 4.  Odd and likely central, is the fact that it shows as 100% free.

Of course if i look at my macrium images, its not free.  If i explore said partition with minitool partition wizard, its not free (winre.wim is present, reagent.xml is present, and boot.sdi is present and accounted for)

[image: This has failed]

[image: This is what bcdedit enum shows]

I'm at a loss as far as how to get windows back pointed towards the recovery partition properly.  I realize the means exists to place the wim anywhere, however i'd like it to be functionally sound like windows intended/created on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not really AN answer as much as MY answer.   However after going through the ringer, one of the following fixed it.

Either the application of a drive letter and removal of said drive letter to the recovery partition, or running a chkdsk against the recovery partition whilst it had said drive letter.

After the aforementioned i checked disk management, and suddenly it wasnt showing as empty space.   I checked reagentc /info and it showed as enabled with a path.

i tested with creation of a recovery drive and voila.

i guess one of those windows things.

Either way, something to try if you've been down the entire checklist of other options related to your non-functional recovery partition.